# Fixing position of nodes in a multiplex network plot using pymnet

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a multiplex network but would like to have the nodes in each layer ordered in a line (as a path).

So far my code is as follows, but it draws the nodes more in a square position. I would like to fix their position (even if manually) so that they are in a line.

```
import string
import random
import numpy as np
# setting initial conditions
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
n_countries = 4
n_layers = 3
layer_name = [alphabet[i] for i in range(n_layers)]

# making categorial multiplex
coupling_weight = 1
cnet = MultiplexNetwork(couplings=('categorical',coupling_weight))
# adding nodes
for i in range(n_countries):
    cnet.add_node(i)
# adding layers
for l in layer_name:
    cnet.add_layer(l)
# adding edges
for l in range(n_layers):
    cnet[l ,(l + 1) % n_countries,alphabet[l],alphabet[l]] = 1
# plotting
random.seed(3)
fig = draw(cnet,show=True)
```

The plot I get is this one.[image: multiplex]
I know pymnet uses matplotlib, perhaps using some matplotlib commands it could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node positions can be fixed using args nodeCoords={} and nodelayerCoords={}. To have the nodes in a line adding the following code works:

```
ncoord = {}
ncoord[0] = (1,1)
ncoord[1] = (2,1)
ncoord[2] = (3,1)
ncoord[3] = (4,1)
#nlaycoord = {}
fig = draw(cnet,show=True, nodeCoords=ncoord)
```

[image]